# Having problem with creating a dataloader class in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, adam, dataloader

I am building a neural network for Bengali numerical digit classification using PyTorch. I am facing difficulties building the dataset class to load my dataset using a data loader. I have a folder with all the images (numerical digits from 0-9) and a CSV file with 2 columns, the first column contains the name of the image, and the second contains the label(0-9). This is my data loader class which probably isn't causing the error.

```
class BDRWDataset(Dataset):
"""BDRW dataset."""

def __init__(self, csv_file, imgs_dir, transform=None):
    """
    Args:
        csv_file (string): Path to the csv file with labels.
        imgs_dir (string): Directory with all the images.
        transform (callable, optional): Optional transform to be applied
            on a sample.
    """
    self.labels = pd.read_csv(csv_file).iloc[:, 1].to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)
    self.imgs_dir = imgs_dir
    self.transform = transform

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.labels)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    if torch.is_tensor(idx):
        idx = idx.tolist()

    img_path = '/content/BDRW_train/digit_' + str(idx) + '.jpg'
    image = io.imread(img_name, plugin='matplotlib')
    image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(image))
    label = self.labels[idx]
    label = float(label)

    if self.transform:
        image = self.transform(image)        

    return (image, label)
```

I create an instance of this class.

```
transformed_dataset = BDRWDataset(csv_file='/content/labels.csv',imgs_dir='/content/BDRW_train',
                              transform=transforms.Compose([
                                           Rescale((28, 28)),
                                           transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,)),
                                           ToTensor()
                                           ]))
```

I have defined rescale and to tensor as follows

```
class Rescale(object):
"""Rescale the image in a sample to a given size.

Args:
    output_size (tuple or int): Desired output size. If tuple, output is
        matched to output_size. If int, smaller of image edges is matched
        to output_size keeping aspect ratio the same.
"""

def __init__(self, output_size):
    assert isinstance(output_size, (int, tuple))
    self.output_size = output_size

def __call__(self, sample):
    image, label = sample

    h, w = image.shape[:2]
    if isinstance(self.output_size, int):
        if h > w:
            new_h, new_w = self.output_size * h / w, self.output_size
        else:
            new_h, new_w = self.output_size, self.output_size * w / h
    else:
        new_h, new_w = self.output_size

    new_h, new_w = int(new_h), int(new_w)

    img = transform.resize(image, (new_h, new_w))

    return img, label

class ToTensor(object):
"""Convert ndarrays in sample to Tensors."""

def __call__(self, sample):
    image, label = sample['image'], sample['label']

    # swap color axis because
    # numpy image: H x W x C
    # torch image: C X H X W
    image = image.transpose((2, 0, 1))
    return (torch.from_numpy(image), torch.from_numpy(label))
```

Splitting the dataset into test and train and created train loader and validation loader using torch.utils.data.DataLoader

The neural network is

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(CNN, self).__init__()
    self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2))
    self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2))
    self.fc = nn.Linear(7*7*32, 10)

def forward(self, x):
    out = self.layer1(x)
    out = self.layer2(out)
    out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
    out = self.fc(out)
    return out
```

I create an instance of this class and start training

```
cnn = CNN()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(cnn.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
```

```
losses = [];
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (image, label) in enumerate(valloader):
        image = Variable(image.float())
        label = Variable(label)

        # Forward + Backward + Optimize
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = cnn(image)
        loss = criterion(output, label)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        losses.append(loss.data[0]);

        if (i+1) % 100 == 0:
            print ('Epoch : %d/%d, Iter : %d/%d,  Loss: %.4f' 
                   %(epoch+1, num_epochs, i+1, len(train_dataset)//batch_size, loss.data[0]))
```

This is where I get the error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2812     try:
-> 2813         fp.seek(0)
   2814     except (AttributeError, io.UnsupportedOperation):

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2813         fp.seek(0)
   2814     except (AttributeError, io.UnsupportedOperation):
-> 2815         fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
   2816         exclusive_fp = True
   2817 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

It refers to PIL Image which I have used in the dataloader. So it seems to me that's where I am doing something wrong.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17XdP7gUoMNLxPCJ6PHEi3B09UQItzKyf?usp=sharing

This is the notebook I am working on. Please help me debug the errors in the code.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DznuHV9Fi5jVEbGdP-tg3ckmp5CNDOj1

This is the dataset I am working on.

Comment: Can you put your error in a better format along with the code snippet where you are getting the error instead of the whole notebook? It becomes quite difficult to debug when you post the whole notebook.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll update the question.